# I get an error in backend , when I try to see the orders, or the products in cataolg I get "Whoops, our bad..."

Tags: magento2, admin, error

I'm using magento 2.0.7, I've tryed to update to 2.1 but I got some errors, so I restored a complete backup back to 2.0.7. The frontend works fine, but when I go in backend, some pages doesn't work.. basicly if I go to catalog products, or orders for exmaple, I get a page like the website's one, but with "Whoops, our bad...The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
" error. I have tryed to deploy, upgrade, clean the cache.. but nothing.. I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you also restore the database from the backup?

Comment: yes I have also restored the database, but the strange thing is that some products that I have added after the restore date, are still in also after the restore.. when I log into admin it shows me 2.0.7, as it should.. and no 2.1

Comment: How did you restore the database? A simple MySQL import without dropping the DB or removing all tables could lead to such strange effects.

Comment: Without dropping the DB.. you think is that?

Comment: Yes. It would mean you new and old database is mixed together